# Python Select first word in a string without using methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework assignment where I have to select the first word in a string. Normally I would do this:

```
s = "Hello World"
words = s.split()
first_word = words[0]
print(first_word)
```

For this assignment I cannot use methods or loops to answer the question. Any ideas?

Comment: loop through the whole text to check for a space then get the substring from start of the text upto the index of the space.

Comment: What are you learning about in school now? That might be a hint.

Comment: `re.match(r'^.+\b',s).group(0)`?

Comment: I dont think you can do this without looping, maybe some list comprehension wizard can help.

Comment: When you say you can't use 'methods' do you mean you can't write your own method/function or you are simply not allowed to use functions from libraries?

Comment: not allowed to use the functions from libraries

Answer (score 2):

Find the index of the first space character, then use string slicing:

```
s = "Hello World"

print(s[:s.index(' ')])
```

No loops, but does use the `.index()` method...

Could also try a recursive function:

```
s = "Hello World"


def first_word(string):

    if string[0] == ' ':
        return ''
    else:
        new_string = string[0] + first_word(string[1:])
    return new_string


print(first_word(s))
```

Comment: can't use methods unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't use methods and loops, you could do it using recursion.

```py
def r(a, b=''):
     if len(a) == 0 or a[0] == ' ':
         return b
     return r(a[1:], b + a[0])

s = 'Hello World'
print(r(s))
```

would print `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be fine

```
s = "Hello World"
s.split()[0]
```

but a way without any method could be

```
s[0:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursion is very similar to MacieK's:

(edited to allow non space word delimiters)

```
def hello(s):

    delims = ' ,-'

    if s == '' or s[:1] in delims: return

    print(s[:1], end='')

    hello(s[1:])

hello('Hello, World')
```